# continue extracting a tarball after job is killed

Tags: linux, tar, extract

I am extracting a big tarball, but the job was killed in the midway. 
Is it possible to continue extraction without rolling back from the beginning? 
The command I was using was

```
tar xvf foo.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer:** `--skip-old-files`

**Longer answer:** `tar --skip-old-files -xvf aoeu.tar` will make tar silently ignore any files that has a corresponding output file. It is also possible to use the `-k` flag, but this will result in tar throwing an error and cowardly refuse to do anything further. However, I am not sure how a partially extracted file will be treated, so you may have to identify those manually and do those individually (if tar was aborted mid-operation, there should be only one not matching in size and content).

Comment: He could do a `--diff` or `--compare` afterwards to check for any corrupted files.

Comment: This does not seem to work. After adding this option, it gives me an error message of "tar: --keep-old-files: Cannot open: No such file or directory. tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now. Could it be because of a bug of tar? They seem to have a patch, but it is not pushed to the official release yet? (see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198588/use-tar-to-extract-and-immediately-compress-files-from-tarball)